# Why "predicate" instead of "object"?

Tags: terminology

English is not my native language and I am not a logician but I currently study on a topic related to categorical statements. Here is a categorical statement:

> All (quantifier) ravens (subject term) are (copula) birds (predicate term).

I think, the predicate of the statement is not only "birds" but "are birds". If I am correct, why do we call it "predicate" instead of calling "object"?

If we generalise these kind of statements to Quantifier Term-1 Verb Term-2 (e.g. All ravens like people), is "people" still a predicate or an object?

Bonus questions: Is "All ravens like people" considered as categorical statement? What should I call "like" (maybe a verb or a role or a property)?

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. Is this a question about formalisation in logic or about English grammar? If the latter, it's more appropriate for [english.se] perhaps. If the first, then it would be most intuitive (for me at least) to see 'are' and 'birds' together as the predicate, e.g. ∀ r∈Ravens, isBird(r). Then, in 'all ravens like people' the predicate would be 'r likes people'. (Oh, and I removed your thanks, because we generally don't add footers to our posts here. Read more about it [here](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/behavior))

Comment: In [categorical statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition) **all** terms are *predicates*; the "logical form" of "All ravens are birds" is : **∀x (Raven(x) → Bird(x))**. The logical form of "All ravens like people" depends on wether we consider the "universe of discourse" made of all objects whatever; in this case we have **∀x∀y ((Raven(x) ∧ People(y)) → Likes(x,y))**.

Comment: Note. "All ravens like people" is not a categorical statement": in the original [Aristotelian logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/), there are no *binary* relations, but only *unary* (monadic) predicates.

Answer (score 1):

In conventional linguistics, we might call "birds" a **predicate nominative**, while "are birds" would be the full **predicate**. The full **subject** is "all ravens", which the sentences asserts satisfies the predicate "are birds". In languages that support case distinction, a predicate involving an equative verb (copula) [usually uses the nominative case](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/declensions.html), which is the reason the **noun phrase** in it is called the predicate nominative.

For **finite verbs**, however, such as in "All ravens like people.", you have a **subject** and an **object**, namely "all ravens" and "people". In languages with case declension, you will usually find "people" in the **accusative** case. In English you will say "All ravens like me.", not "All ravens like I.". The whole predicate is still "like people". In general one might say that a **declarative sentence** is of the form NP+Pred where NP is a noun phrase and Pred is a predicate.

Whether a sentence is categorical or not does not have much to do with the syntax, although it tends to use universal quantifiers. The fundamental criterion for being categorical is that the sentence says something about a whole group. For example consider "Flowers bloom and fall.", which has not one quantifier and even uses the present tense, but which every native speaker will correctly interpret as being about the general fact that all flowers bloom and then eventually fall.

Answer (score 0):

The distinction here is between logic and language.

We use language to describe the world, the world is full of change - it is not changeless - ergo we must be able to describe change. Aristotle said that change requires the following:

> a. something that has the capacity to cause change and actually cause it
>
> b. something that has the capacity to be changed and actually be changed.

in language the first requirement is called the subject: a subject is something - a he, or she, or an it - that can cause change; the second requirement is the object: it is something that can be changed.

In these requirements the notion of change is left undetermined. To determine it, we must use a verb - ie hit or chase

So we have sentences such as:

> Rob Roy kicked the ball
>
> Sherlock Holmes chased the thief

To connect this to the above we can just point out that

> Rob has the capacity to kick the ball (he's a footballer), and the ball has the capacity to be kicked (its a football).

and

> Sherlock Holmes has the capacity to chase (he's a detective) and the thief has the capacity to be chased; in short they're both men.

These aren't the kind of sentences that are used in logic which derive from a different notion of language - language which doesn't describe change but describes state - so in a way - out of time, or timeless; and isn't logic, in a way, out of time or timeless?

> The tree is red
>
> The house is big

Here, though the word 'is' is called a verb, it isn't fulfilling a verbal function, in the sense of describing change, it is describing state - hence its called a copula; in essence its function here is adjectival - and there is no object. We could alternatively have said:

> red tree
>
> big house

Its this notion that Aristotle puts into service in propositional logic as the predicate.

> IsRed(tree)
>
> IsBig(house)

where IsRed and IsBig are both predicates and house and tree are subjects. There is no object here.